# Splice array(of arrays) Javascript (what am i doing wrong)

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, simulation, array-splice

Hi everyone i'm trying to create a sort of mini textual game where each player gets assigned a random character (each character have a certain amount of power that decrease after each fight by the amount of the power of the character he defeated) here is the funcion where all the fun happens

```js
var characters = [
  'c1',
  'c2',
  'c3',
  'c4',
  'c5',
  'c6',
  'c7',
  'c8',
  'c9',
  'c10'
]
var PL = [
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4,
  5,
  6,
  7,
  8,
  9,
  10
]
new_arr[0] = gra_arr;
//the gra_arr is an array withe name of the players that i take from the user (that happens in another part of the code)
new_arr[1] = characters;
new_arr[2] = PL;

start = function() {

    new_arr[0] = gra_arr;
    new_arr[1] = characters;
    new_arr[2] = PL;

    function shuffle(array) {
      var currentIndex = array[1].length,
        temporaryValue, randomIndex;
      var currentIndex2 = array[2].length,
        temporaryValue2;

      // While there remain elements to shuffle...
      while (0 !== currentIndex) {

        // Pick a remaining element...
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;
        currentIndex2 -= 1;

        // And swap it with the current element.
        temporaryValue = array[1][currentIndex];
        array[1][currentIndex] = array[1][randomIndex];
        array[1][randomIndex] = temporaryValue;

        temporaryValue2 = array[2][currentIndex2];
        array[2][currentIndex2] = array[2][randomIndex];
        array[2][randomIndex] = temporaryValue2;
      }
      return array;
    }

    shuffle(new_arr);

    set1 = function(array1) {
      for (i = 0; i < array1[0].length; i++) {
        new_arr[0][i] = new_arr[0][i] + " - " + new_arr[1][i];
      }
    }
    set1(new_arr);

    print_list = function(div_id, grp_vett, grp) {
      var ul = $("<ul>");
      var h1 = $("<h1>")
      var span = $("<span>").text(grp);
      h1.append(span);
      $(div_id).append(ul);
      $(div_id).prepend(h1);
      for (i = 0; i < grp_vett.length; i++) {
        var h12 = $("<h3>").html(grp_vett[i]);
        var li = $("<li>").append(h12);
        ul.append(li);
      }
    }

    print_list("#gra1", new_arr[0], "Assignments");

    //RESHUFFLE
    function shuffle(array) {
      var currentIndex = array[0].length,
        temporaryValue, randomIndex;
      var currentIndex2 = array[0].length,
        temporaryValue2;
      var currentIndex3 = array[0].length,
        temporaryValue3;

      // While there remain elements to shuffle...
      while (0 !== currentIndex) {

        // Pick a remaining element...
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;
        currentIndex2 -= 1;
        currentIndex3 -= 1;

        // And swap it with the current element.
        temporaryValue = array[0][currentIndex];
        array[0][currentIndex] = array[0][randomIndex];
        array[0][randomIndex] = temporaryValue;

        temporaryValue2 = array[1][currentIndex2];
        array[1][currentIndex2] = array[1][randomIndex];
        array[1][randomIndex] = temporaryValue2;

        temporaryValue3 = array[2][currentIndex3];
        array[2][currentIndex3] = array[2][randomIndex];
        array[2][randomIndex] = temporaryValue3;
      }
      return array;
    }

    shuffle(new_arr);

    var round = 0;

    matches = function() {
      round += 1;
      var h1 = $("<h1>").text("Round " + round + " Matches");
      var x = $("#r1");
      x.append(h1);

      var arCopy = new_arr;
      for (i = 0; i < arCopy[0].length; i += 2) {

        if (arCopy[2][i] > arCopy[2][i + 1]) {

          new_arr[0].splice(i + 1, 1)
          new_arr[1].splice(i + 1, 1)
          new_arr[2].splice(i + 1, 1)
        } else {
          new_arr[0].splice(i, 1)
          new_arr[1].splice(i, 1)
          new_arr[2].splice(i, 1)
        }
      }
    }

    matches();
```

basically when i did my first test (assuming all 3 arrays had length of 10) and looked at the console i was expecting new_arr[0],new_arr[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oW7vm.png),new_arr[2] to have length of 5 but they have length of 6 
[image]

Eventually my goal is to do that until there is just 1 player left

```js
matches = function() {
  round += 1;
  var h1 = $("<h1>").text("Round " + round + " Matches");
  var x = $("#r1");
  x.append(h1);

  while (new_arr[0].length > 1) {
    var arCopy = new_arr;
    for (i = 0; i < arCopy[0].length; i += 2) {

      if (arCopy[2][i] > arCopy[2][i + 1]) {
        new_arr[0].splice(i + 1, 1)
        new_arr[1].splice(i + 1, 1)
        new_arr[2].splice(i + 1, 1)
      } else {
        new_arr[0].splice(i, 1)
        new_arr[1].splice(i, 1)
        new_arr[2].splice(i, 1)
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When you have related data, it's usually best to use a single array of objects, rather than separate arrays for each.

Comment: You have two functions named `shuffle`.

Comment: i tried with objects but my current knowledge of objects is a bit "limited"  so i tried with arrays, about the function i didn't noticed thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found myself the problem, basically i was changing the length of the array i was referring to in the for so instead of changing his length i change the values and later i'll remove them

```
matches = function(){
    round += 1;
    var h1 = $("<h1>").text("Round "+round+" Matches");
    var x = $("#r1");
    x.append(h1);
        if(new_arr[0].length %2 == 0){

        for(i = 0; i<new_arr[0].length;i= i+2){
            var h1 = $('<h1>').html(new_arr[0][i] +" PL = " +new_arr[2][i] + " VS " + new_arr[0][i+1]+" PL = " +new_arr[2][i+1])
            if(new_arr[2][i]>new_arr[2][i+1]){
                new_arr[2][i] =new_arr[2][i] -new_arr[2][i+1]
                new_arr[0][i+1] = "defeated"
                new_arr[1][i+1] = "defeated"
                new_arr[2][i+1] = "defeated"
            }else{
                new_arr[2][i+1] =new_arr[2][i+1] -new_arr[2][i]
                new_arr[0][i] = "defeated"
                new_arr[1][i] = "defeated"
                new_arr[2][i] = "defeated"
            }
            x.append(h1);
            }
        }else{

        }      
}   
matches();
```